# Lookup Field to pull in values from Choice Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience, choice-field

I have a `Customer` Table containing info such as Customer # (Number), Name(Single line of text), Bankruptcy status (Yes/No), Currency (Choice).

I also have a `Invoice` table which has a lookup column for the Customer #, pulling in the Customer Name.

Now, the scope of the project has made it so I need to pull in the Currency column using the Customer # lookup, which *seems* like it would've been straight forward; however, I don't see any of the other columns besides the system generated ones (Version, Title, ID, Created, etc.)

How can I get the lookup column to also include the currency in the `Invoice` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved this problem and will try my best to document on how I did it and what I needed to consider.

First, I changed the **Currency** to type: **Single Line of Text**

Second, I went into my **PowerApp** and for each **display cards** (in Galleries) showing this I removed the `.Value` from the end of its references, allowing the display field to properly pull the existing text.

Next, for all **Forms** I removed the field entirely (as I've had issues where PowerApps maintains some back-end data-type designations that create issues).

Then, I re-added it and simply changed the **Control Type** to a **Allowed Values**, and made in the Allowed Values section overwrote `Parent.Default` with [ "Option1", "Option2", etc...] (for syntax).

Lastly, I went to the Invoice List and under the `Customer #` Lookup column I selected the additional `Currency` column to be pulled into the table

Comment: Hi Mark S. Thanks or your enthusiastic sharing, this is indeed a good workaround. You can accept your answer as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.

Comment: @EchoDu_MSFT I'm happy to help support a communal learning environment and am happy to report back with my findings if it helps others. I'm just waiting for the 24 hr cooldown from when I answer to when I can accept it. 7 hours to go.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Choice column using lookup columns is **not supported** in SharePoint.

**Supported Column Types**:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Unsupported Column Types**:

- Multiple lines of text
- Currency
- Person or Group
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Yes/No
- Choice
- Lookup

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Answer (score 0):

Extending Choice column using lookup columns is not supported in SharePoint.
However, you can try to the below workaround:

1.On the Customer list, set "**Customer #**" as **Singel line of text** column

[image]

2.On the Invoice list, create the same "**Currency**"(Choice) field as the Customer list

[image]

3.Create a Microsoft Flow

- a.Go to the Invoice list, click on **Integrate** >> **Power
  Automate** >> **Create a flow**

[image]

- b.flow

[image]

- c.Save and Test it

4.When you create a new item in the Invoice list, wait a few seconds and refresh the page, you will find that the "**Currency**" field will be filled in automatically.

[image]